# Prevent Caching .svg Images on Application Server

Tags: apache, caching, svg, batik

I have a JWS application that caches several different resource types. However, I do not want to cache .svg images. It seems that the framework does not honor the server side cache control HTTP headers that I have set.

I was wondering if there is some other way that I could load .svg images without caching. I am open to putting a solution in my `loadSVGDocument()` method, but my code is currently built around Apache Batik for loading .svg files. Is there a solution to pass an `InputStream` with a noCache flag within the Batik library similar to what `DocumentBuilderFactory` provides below?

```
URL url = new URL(fileLocation);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
// Prevent JavaWebStart from returning cached copy.
connection.setUseCaches(false);

// Now fetch the content, e.g.
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document doc = db.parse(connection.getInputStream());
```

Here is my current `loadSVGDocument()` method that uses several Apache Batik fields:

```
public void loadSVGDocument(final String url)
{
    System.out.println("THE SVG URL: " + url);
    String oldURI = null;
    if (svgDocument != null)
    {
       oldURI = svgDocument.getURL();
    }

    final ParsedURL newURI = new ParsedURL(oldURI, url);
    String theUrl = newURI.toString();
    fragmentIdentifier = newURI.getRef();

    loader = new DocumentLoader(userAgent);
    nextDocumentLoader = new SVGDocumentLoader(theUrl, loader);
    nextDocumentLoader.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);

    Iterator it = svgDocumentLoaderListeners.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
       nextDocumentLoader
          .addSVGDocumentLoaderListener((SVGDocumentLoaderListener) it.next());
    }

    documentLoader = nextDocumentLoader;
    nextDocumentLoader = null;
    documentLoader.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I found that I can call Batik's

`DocumentLoader.loadDocument(URL url, InputStream is)`

with the setUseCaches flag as false. Not only does this load the image, but it also removes it from the cache accordingly. Though not the best solution in the sense that it would be nice for JWS to honor my HTTP headers, this work-around is good enough.